# ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException while running Arduino IDE on PI

Tags: java, arduino, raspberry-pi, arduino-ide

When i am opening my Arduino IDE on my Raspberry PI 4, its getting JAVA Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.app.I18n._(I18n.java:51)
    at processing.app.Preferences.init(Preferences.java:210)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:117)
```

Not sure why this is happening.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @Stultuske The IDE itself is throwing the error, not the code he wrote.

Comment: @gre_gor for all we know his ide automatically runs something. if it is the ide, his best(better) option is to ask his question on the official pages of the IDE

Answer (score -1):

i advise you to use optional to avoid NPE
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

```
optional<Integer> optional
        = Optional.ofNullable(9455);
```

Comment: I am running my Arduino IDE on terminal of my PI and getting this error. I am not running any type of Java code. I am just getting this error while running IDE from PI Terminal.